# how to config jax-ws Handler in Spring?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I  according jax-ws API integration jax-ws with Spring ,but I get an exception at my webservice project,here is API site :http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/ ,I have same config xml in my project,but i get an exception is below:

```
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'handlers'                   is not allowed to appear in element 'ws:service'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
```

who can give me solution?

Answer (score 6):

The example given is wrong and not valid with regard to the schema. handlers is not an attribute, but a nested element. Use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd">


 <wss:binding url="/services/demo">
     <wss:service>
         <ws:service bean="#demoEndpoint">
             <ws:handlers>
                 <ref bean="demoHandler"/>
             </ws:handlers>
         </ws:service>
     </wss:service>
 </wss:binding>
</bean>
```